# How to run custom task within gradle build?

Tags: gradle, npm, build.gradle, npm-install

I have a Spring Boot web application which uses Gradle and NPM. I created a `package.json` file and `npm install` works fine. But I'd like to be able to run `npm install` automatically when I run `gradle build`. Here's my build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id "org.ysb33r.nodejs.base" version "0.1"
    id "org.ysb33r.nodejs.npm" version "0.1"
}
group 'com.Blahblah'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'


war {
    baseName = 'Blahblah'
    version =  '0.0.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'commons-fileupload', name: 'commons-fileupload', version: '1.3.3'
    compile group: 'com.cloudinary', name: 'cloudinary-core', version: '1.17.0'
    compile group: 'com.cloudinary', name: 'cloudinary-http44', version: '1.17.0'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.6'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jersey', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'

    classpath "gradle.plugin.org.ysb33r.gradle:nodejs-gradle-plugin:0.1"

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

apply plugin: "org.ysb33r.nodejs.base"
apply plugin: "org.ysb33r.nodejs.npm"
```

I added the `ysb33r` parts in `plugins`, `dependencies` and `apply plugin` sections, but now I get an error at the line:

```
classpath "gradle.plugin.org.ysb33r.gradle:nodejs-gradle-plugin:0.1"
```

It says:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Blahblah'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [gradle.plugin.org.ysb33r.gradle:nodejs-gradle-plugin:0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Before I added the `ysb33r` lines, the build worked fine. What could be the problem? And when the problem is solved, how should I proceed in order to run `npm install` automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. `Exec.commandLine` is a String array
2. Your `println` is happening in the configuration phase, put it in a `doLast` block so it executes in the execution phase

Eg:

```
task npmInstall(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'npm install'.split(' ')
    doLast {
        println 'DONE!'
    }
}
```

Rather than calling `npm` via `Exec` task, you should consider one of the gradle/nodejs plugins. Most of these are able to use an embedded nodejs version, downloaded from a repository, to execute nodejs commands rather than require a nodejs installation on the machine

See: https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=nodejs

Eg: http://ysb33rorg.gitlab.io/nodejs-gradle-plugin/

Comment: Hi @lance-java, thanks for the reply. I'm trying to use one of the plugins, but without success... Can you give me an example how should I modify my existing `build.gradle` file in order to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: With zero information, you'll get zero help. Possibly another stack overflow question saying exactly what plugin you are using and what you have tried based on reading the plugin documentation

Comment: I've edited my original question and added more details about what I tried to do and what error message I got.

Comment: That's unfortunate, now your initial question is gone... and my answer doesn't match the question. Better to ask another question regarding the specific gradle plugin you are using